# How do i get the original values after transforming a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have made multiple transofmrtaions on my numpy array like log, reciprocal, boxcox, sqrt, and so on..

```
'''
y_t = np.log(y)
y_t1 = np.sqrt(y)
y_t2  np.reciprocal(y)
y_t3 = np.power(y,0.1)
......
'''
```

And I able to get the values back for log and sqrt

```
'''
y_t_orig = np.exp(y_t)
y_t1_orig = np.square(y_t1)
'''
```

How do i get the values back for other transformations like power, reciprocal , boxcox?

Comment: You are not getting your original values back `np.exp(np.log(y))`  only gives you the numerical approximation of something that mathematically is an identity. You should save the original values (meaning a copy/deep copy of them) in a differenent variable (or external source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need inverse functions, however for `np.reciprocal(y)` the inverse function is also `np.reciprocal(y_t)`, as it is 1/y.

And for `np.power(y, 0.1)` it is `np.power(y, 10)`.

But I would sincerely advise you to think about why this is necessary in the architecture of your application, and check if there is any way to save the original values.

Comment: thanks, I need it because transforming the target variable has drastically improved our model. Will take this forward